# gulp does not recognise tailwind classes

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make config with gulp, sass ad tailwindcss, everything work good, but when I first run gulp i can see my tailwind classes applied but when I try to add more classes I can not see the changes even the server is running and the classes are compiled in my CSS file in dist folder, I should come back and run gulp another time, to see the latest changes.
Here you see my gulpjs config and tailwind config, what I'm doing wrong, I want to be able to see my CSS changes without the need to every time restart the server :/

```
const { series, src, dest, watch } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
let imagemin;
const imagewebp = require('gulp-webp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// css Task
function scssTask() {
  return src('assets/src/scss/app.scss', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(postcss([cssnano(), tailwindcss()]))
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

// Js Task
function jsTask() {
  return src('assets/src/js/*.js', { sourcemaps: true })
    .pipe(babel({ presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }))
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(dest('dist', { sourcemaps: '.' }));
}

const optimizeimg = series(
    async () => {
        imagemin = await import('gulp-imagemin');
    },
    () => src('assets/src/images/**/*')
        .pipe(
            imagemin.default(
                [
                    imagemin.mozjpeg({ quality: 80, progressive: true }),
                    imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 2})
                ]))
        .pipe(dest('./dist/images'))
);

//optimize and move images
function webpImage() {
  return src('dist/images/*.{jpg,png}') // change to your source directory
    .pipe(imagewebp())
    .pipe(dest('dist/images')) // change to your final/public directory
};

function browserSyncServer(cb) {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './',
    },
    notify: {
      styles: {
        top: 'auto',
        bottom: '0',
      },
    },
  });
  cb();

}

function browserSyncReload(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb();
}

function watchTasks(cb) {
  watch('*.html', browserSyncReload);
  watch(
    ['assets/src/scss/**/*.scss', 'assets/src/scss/*.scss', 'assets/src/images/*.{png,jpg}'],
    series(scssTask,optimizeimg,webpImage, browserSyncReload)
  );
  cb();
}
exports.default = series(scssTask, optimizeimg,webpImage,browserSyncServer, watchTasks);

exports.build = series(scssTask,optimizeimg, webpImage);
```

my tailwind config file

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./assets/src/**/*.html',
    './assets/src/**/*.js',
    './assets/src/**/*.scss',
    './index.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When changes occur in HTML, you reload the page. To apply the necessary styles, you need to run a task to build them.

```
function watchTasks(cb) {
  watch('*.html', scssTask, browserSyncReload);
  watch(
    ['assets/src/scss/**/*.scss', 'assets/src/scss/*.scss', 'assets/src/images/*.{png,jpg}'],
    series(scssTask,optimizeimg,webpImage, browserSyncReload)
  );
  cb();
}
```